# Verify in one SQL query that all items have a state from a list ("IN" condition) and that at least one item has one specific state ("=" condition)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following situation in our database:

- I have a list of `Item`s
- Each `Item` has a `State` column
- Each `Item` belongs to a `Batch`

Now, for a given `Batch` I would like to make sure that...

1. ...all its `Item`s are either in a state named "Paused" or "Finished", and
2. ...at least one of its `Item`s is in the "Finished" state.

Here are some possible state combinations and their result for a `Batch` with 3 `Item`s:

| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | **Result** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finished | Paused | Paused | **Valid** |
| Finished | Finished | Paused | **Valid** |
| Finished | Finished | Finished | **Valid** |
| Paused | Paused | Paused | **Invalid** *(no item is "Finished")* |
| Finished | Paused | Canceled | **Invalid** *(one item is neither "Finished" nor "Paused")* |
| Canceled | Running | Running | **Invalid** *(both conditions are **not** met)* |

**My question is: How can I combine these two conditions into one SQL query?**

So far, I have only found a way to check the conditions separately, but I do not like the approach because I select from the same table twice with only slightly modified `WHERE` clause. Note that the example is extremely simplified. In reality, I do not simply select from an `Item` table, but the query includes several JOINs which I currently repeat in both queries. That's what I would like to avoid.

```sql
DECLARE @batchId INT = 123

IF (EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM Item item
    WHERE item.BatchId = @batchId AND state.Name NOT IN ('Paused', 'Finished')
))
BEGIN
    -- fail because at least one item is not paused or finished
END

IF (NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM Item item
    WHERE item.BatchId = @batchId AND item.State = 'Finished'
))
BEGIN
    -- fail because no item is finished
END
```

Comment: Do you want to do this for a single `BatchId` or for all of them at once? If the latter, do you want a result showing passes, fails or both?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and representative sample data helps us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can use straightforward conditional aggregation:**

```sql
SELECT
    BatchId,
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN i.state NOT IN ('Paused', 'Finished') THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
           COUNT(CASE WHEN i.state = 'Finished' THEN 1 END) > 0
        THEN 'Passed'
        ELSE 'Fail'
    END AS Result
FROM Item i
GROUP BY BatchId
```

If you want to keep your existing logic and do it by `BatchId` with an `IF` then just filter on that:

```sql
DECLARE @batchId INT = 123

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Item i
    WHERE BatchId = @batchId
    HAVING
        COUNT(CASE WHEN i.state NOT IN ('Paused', 'Finished') THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
        COUNT(CASE WHEN i.state = 'Finished' THEN 1 END) > 0
    )) 
BEGIN
      -- Fail
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Use a table variable to hold results
DECLARE @Results table (StatePauseCount integer,
                        StateFinishedCount integer,
                        ItemFinishedCount integer)

--Perform one select into the table which counts all relevant states / conditions
INSERT INTO @Results
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN state.Name = 'Paused' AND item.BatchID = @BatchID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatePauseCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN state.NAME = 'Finished' AND item.BatchID = @BatchID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StateFinishedCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN item.State = 'Finished' AND item.BatchID = @BatchID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ItemFinishedCount
  FROM Item item

--Use the results in the table variable to define pass / fail
    IF (SELECT StatePauseCount + StateFinishedCount FROM @Results) = 0
 BEGIN
       -- Fail because no item is paused or finished
   END 

    IF (SELECT ItemFinishedCount FROM @Results) = 0
 BEGIN
       -- Fail because no item is finished
   END
```